# React update upon props changing in depth

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which takes in a matrix as an input (actually an object which has matrix and getter and setter, but that is irrelevant) and renders a table based on it. The table cells should be text inputs and should change the matrix when the value in them is changed. How do I do that without using a force update? Here is sample working code (this is the App.js in a create-react-app):

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const nodes = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
];

function useForceUpdate() {
    const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);

    return () => setFlag(!flag);
}

function Component({nodes}) {
    const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();

    const handleOnClick = (i,j) => {
        nodes[i][j]++;
        forceUpdate();
    };

    return (
        <thead>
            {nodes.map((row,i)=>
                <tr>
                    {row.map((el,j)=>
                        <td onClick={()=>handleOnClick(i, j)}>{el}</td>
                    )}
                </tr>
            )}
        </thead>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <Component nodes={nodes} />
    );
}

export default App;
```

You can try it on CodePen from this link: https://codepen.io/askenderski/pen/dyNRyxJ

Comment: Don't mutate state (or in this case props, arguably even worse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the right way to go about it would be to have `nodes` as a state and pass it and a `setNodes` as a prop to your `Component` and then trigger the update from your child like so (take a note of the `newNode` as a copy of `nodes`) :-

```
    
    function Component({nodes,setNodes}) {  
  
        const handleOnClick = (i,j) => {
          let newNodes = nodes.map(row=>[...row]);
          newNodes[i][j]+=1;
          setNodes(newNodes);
        };
    
        return (
            <thead>
                {nodes.map((row,i)=>
                    <tr>
                        {row.map((el,j)=>
                            <td onClick={()=>handleOnClick(i, j)}>{el}</td>
                        )}
                    </tr>
                )}
            </thead>
        );
    }
    
    function App() {
        const [nodes,setNodes] = React.useState([
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]
    ]);
        return ( <Component nodes={nodes} setNodes={setNodes} />
        );
    }

ReactDOM.render(
  <App></App>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

So if your source of truth comes from above (props instead of state) then you need to pass down a handler as well:

```js
const SomeParentComponent = () => {
   // making an assumption that the immediate parent
   // holds the nodes as state - it could come from anywhere
   // "above" your component
   const [matrix,setMatrix] = useState(theMatrix);

   // this is the handler that will update your state
   const handleChangeNode = (i,j) => {
   
     // always reurn a new matrix, which is why you do matrix.map
     setMatrix(matrix => matrix.map((row,idx) => {

       // not interested in changing this one, return the same reference
       if(idx !== i) return e;

       // change this one
       return row.map((col,idx2) => {
         // not interested in changing this one
         if(idx2 !== j) return col;

         // change this one
         return col++;
       });
     });
   }

   return <YourComponent nodes={matrix} handleChangeNode={handleChangeNode}/>
}
```

Don't mutate stuff in react. If you want to update an object/array (or some property nested within that object/array) always return a new object/array.

Answer (score 0):

Just `useState` is enough for that

**[Demo link](https://codepen.io/prasanth1036/pen/vYgZELa?editors=1010)**

```
  const [nodeList,setNodeList] = React.useState(nodes);
    
        const handleOnClick = (i,j) => {
            let nodesCopy = [...nodeList];
            nodesCopy[i][j]++;
            setNodeList(nodesCopy)
        };
```

Comment: You're still mutating the array at `nodeList[i]`. It might work for this specific case, but mutating anything should be avoided unless you know what you're doing (doesn't seem like the OP does).

Comment: @Adam yes but i have copied the value before `++`. it does not mutate the `nodelist`. spread operator also immutable and its cloning the object or array. check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWO7y.png . can you explain  bit more

Comment: I didn't say it mutates nodeList, I said you're still mutating the array at `nodeList[i]`, which, depending on implementation, may or may not matter.